Is this expression always greater than $1$?
I was working with probability functions for the binomial and hypergeometric distributions and I came across the following expression;
$$
\frac{(a x)! (a (n - x))!}{(a n)!} \frac{n!}{x! (n - x)!} \left(\frac{N^
     n}{(N - K)^{n - x} K^x}\right)^{a - 1}
$$
Assume positive integers with $N>K,N>n>x$ and $a$ is a real number greater than 1.
As $a$ increases, the part of the expression with the factorials decreases and the part with the powers increases. I tried plotting it for different values of the variables and it seems that this expression is always greater than $1$. Heres the Mathematica code;
Manipulate[
 Plot[((((a x)! (a (n - x))!)/(a n)!) n!/(x! (n - x)!)) (Nx^
       n/((Nx - Kx)^(n - x) Kx^x))^(a - 1), {a, 1, 2}, 
  PlotRange -> All], {Nx, 10, 1000, 1}, {Kx, 1, Nx, 
  1}, {n, 5, Nx, 1}, {x, 1, n, 1}]

How can I prove that this is indeed greater than $1$?
EDIT
For my purpose, I can relax the problem so that $ax$ and $an$ are positive integers.

First eliminate $K$: replace $\frac{N^
n}{(N - K)^{n - x} K^x}$ by its maximum value.

@AnneBauval Probably you meant the minimal value.

@user Yes, I meant the minimal value. Actually, I calculated $\max_{r\in[0,1]}(1-r)^{n-x}r^x$.

I'm thinking Stirling's Approximation might have some insights.

$\def\d{\,{\rm d}}$
It is advantageous to start from the very beginning with the continuous real non-negative variables $n,x,N,K$ instead of integer ones with the convention $z!=\Gamma(z+1)$.
As suggested in the comment we start with elimination of the last factor replacing it with its minimal (for given $n,x$) value. For this introducing $r=\frac KN$ we need to find the maximum of
$$
(1-r)^{n-x}r^x
$$
which is $\left(1-\frac xn\right)^{n-x}\left(\frac xn\right)^x$. This result encourages us to introduce the variable $t=\frac xn$ $(0\le t\le 1)$. In terms of this variable we need to prove:
$$\frac{\binom{an}{ant}}{\binom n{nt}}\left[(1-t)^{1-t}t^t\right]^{n(a-1)}\le1
.\tag1
$$
Taking logarithm of both sides this inequality is equivalent to
$$
F(n,a,t)\equiv\log\binom{an}{ant}-\log\binom{n}{nt}+n(a-1)\big[(1-t)\log(1-t)+t\log t\big]\le0.\tag2
$$
Observe that for all $n,a$:
$$
F(n,a,0)=F(n,a,1)=0.
$$
Therefore it suffices to prove that $F(n,a,t)$ is a convex function of $t$ for $0\le t\le1$, that is:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{d ^2}{dt^2}F(n,a,t)&= n^2\big[\psi_1(1+nt)+\psi_1(1+n-nt)\big]\\
&-a^2n^2\big[\psi_1(1+ant)+\psi_1(1+an-ant)\big]+n(a-1)\left[\frac 1t+\frac1{1-t}\right]\\
&= \left[n^2\psi_1(1+nt)-a^2n^2\psi_1(1+ant)+\frac{n(a-1)}t\right]\\
&+\left[n^2\psi_1(1+n(1-t))-a^2n^2\psi_1(1+an(1-t))+\frac{n(a-1)}{1-t}\right]>0\tag3,
\end{align}$$
where $\psi_1(z)$ is the trigamma function.
To prove $(3)$ it suffices to demonstrate:
$$
n^2\psi_1(1+nt)-a^2n^2\psi_1(1+ant)+\frac{n(a-1)}t>0\tag4
$$
for $0\le t\le1$.
The inequality $(4)$ rewritten as:
$$
\frac{A^2\psi_1(At)-B^2\psi_1(Bt)}{A-B}<\frac1t\tag5
$$
holds in fact not only for $0\le t\le1$ but for any positive $t$ and $A\ne B$. Using the integral representation of the trigamma function the inequality reads
$$
I_f\equiv\int_0^\infty\frac{z}{1-e^{-z}}\frac{A^2e^{-Atz}-B^2e^{-Btz}}{A-B}\d z<\frac1t.
$$
Two facts about the integrand are important for the proof of the relation which will follow:

$f(z)=\frac z{1-e^{-z}}$ is an increasing convex function of $z$.
The function $w(z;A,B,t)=\frac{A^2e^{-Atz}-B^2e^{-Btz}}{A-B}$ is positive for $0\le z< z_0$ and negative for $z>z_0$ with $z_0=\frac{2\log\frac AB}{(A-B)t}$ (only the fact $z_0>0$ is important, the exact value of $z_0$ does not matter for the following proof).

Now consider the integral
$$
I_g\equiv\int_0^\infty g(z)w(z;A,B,t)\d z
$$
with linear function $g(z)=1+\frac{f(z_0)-1}{z_0}z$, so that $g(0)=f(0)$ and $g(z_0)=f(z_0)$.  In view of convexity of $f(z)$ we have $g(z)>f(z)>0$ for $0< z< z_0$ and $0<g(z)<f(z)$ for $z>z_0$. Therefore:
$$
I_f<I_g=\frac1t,\tag6
$$
where the last equality follows from $\int_0^\infty w(z;A,B,t)\d z=\frac1t$, $\int_0^\infty z\,w(z;A,B,t)\d z=0$.
Thus, inequality $(5)$ is proved and we are done.
PS. I am indebted to River Li for the idea behind the proof of $(5)$.
